# Select values in series based on indices from values in array

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Say I have a series like

```
mySeries = pd.Series(range(1, 100, 1))
myArray = np.array([[3, 10],[6, 9]])
```

How to use values in `myArray` as indices to select `mySeries`?

I would like the resulting array to be `np.array([[4,11],[7, 10]])`.

For example, the (1,1) element in `myArray` is 3, so i would like the (1,1) element in my resulting array to be the 3rd element in `mySeries`, which is 4.

Comment: This is complicated. Your `np,array` is a 2 dimensional array, whereas the Series is designed to be a 1 dimensional ""array"". Using a DataFrame would be possible though, on certain conditions.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution, consisted of first flattening the 2dim array to 1dim, and then recovering the original shape.

```python
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

mySeries = pd.Series(range(1, 100, 1))
myArray = np.array([[3, 10],[6, 9]])

flatArray = np.asarray(mySeries[myArray.ravel()])
resultArray = flatArray.reshape(myArray.shape)

# Output results
print(resultArray)
```

Which outputs:

```
[[ 4 11]
 [ 7 10]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
resultArray = np.empty(shape=len(myArray), dtype=np.ndarray)
for i in range(len(myArray)):
    row = np.empty(shape=len(myArray[i]))
    for k in range(len(myArray[i])):
        v = mySeries[myArray[i,k]]
        row[k] = v
    resultArray[i] = row
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative approach that I think is slightly cleaner:

```py
>>> newArray = mySeries[myArray.flatten()].values
>>> newArray.shape = myArray.shape
>>> newArray
array([[ 4, 11],
       [ 7, 10]], dtype=int64)
```